# Symfony: The class * was not found in the chain configured namespaces UsersBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Model

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I try to follow this tutorial for the pagination: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest3/pagerfanta-pagination

For the moment I have installed the `white-october/pagerfanta-bundle`, and when I made my user repository as following :

```
<?php
// src/UsersBundle/Repository/UserRepository.php
namespace UsersBundle\Repository;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function findAllQueryBuilder() {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('user');
    }

}
```

and in my controller action I did this:

```
<?php
// src/UsersBundle/Controller/UsersController.php

namespace UsersBundle\Controller;

// use statements ...

/**
 * Class UsersController
 *
 * @package UsersBundle\Controller
 *
 * @Rest\RouteResource("user", pluralize=false)
 * @Rest\NamePrefix( "api_v1_" )
 */
class UsersController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface {

    // ...

    /**
     * Responsible to list all the registered users.
     *
     * @Rest\QueryParam(name="page", default="1", requirements="\d+",nullable=true)
     *
     * @return array|\Traversable
     */
    public function getListAction( ParamFetcher $param_fetcher ) {
        if ( ! $this->isGranted( 'ROLE_ADMIN' ) ) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException( 'You do not have sufficient permission to access this resource' );
        }

        $qb = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('UsersBundle\Repository\UserRepository')
            ->findAllQueryBuilder();

        $adapter = new DoctrineORMAdapter( $qb );

        $users = $this->user_manager->findUsers();

        return $users;
    }

    // ...

}
```

I got this output:

`{"code":500,"message":"The class 'UsersBundle\\Repository\\UserRepository' was not found in the chain configured namespaces UsersBundle\\Entity, FOS\\UserBundle\\Model"}`

Anyone knows what that output means? Unfortunately I am totally new to Symfony, and I cannot understand what is the issue for this output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('UsersBundle\Repository\UserRepository')
        ->findAllQueryBuilder();
```

You should find you Repository throug your entity, so something like this

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('User:class')
        ->findAllQueryBuilder();
```

Doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

And in your `User` entity you should have something like this

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User {
...
```

Comment: Just awesome Gregoire Ducharme !! Thank you. It worked like a charm. Thank too much. I will mark your answer as the right one in about 6minutes as the StackOverflow prevent's me to do it right now :) Thanks again !! :)

Comment: No worries ! Good luck B)